# MathJax request

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, mathjax

Although we are only on day 1 of the private beta, I figure we might as well get this request out there. Being a science Stack Exchange site, no doubt math is going to spring up in both questions and answers, and as such an easily accessible method of typesetting equations and general math would be an aid to the site. Can MathJax please be implemented for this site?

Comment: Yup. I'll create a CW list of posts that need MathJax (they want to know that it's actually needed before giving it to us).

Comment: Yeah, I've already noticed 3-4 questions or answers that could use this, and I haven't read much more than a dozen...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$\sum{answers} = MathJax\ enabled$$

Answer (score 26):

### YES!

We really do need MathJax on here. There's going to be a lot of times in which we need to reference formulas, or other such stuff, and MathJax will make everything a lot easier in these cases. The Stack Exchange team looks for posts that would benefit by having MathJax, so let's make a list of such posts.

Some posts that could use this:

- [How is ocean heat content measured?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/16/how-is-ocean-heat-uptake-measured/59#59)
- [How is the mass of the Earth determined?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/88/how-is-the-mass-of-the-earth-determined/89#89)
- [Why do Tsunamis travel slower than sound?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/113/why-do-tsunamis-travel-slower-than-sound/)
- [How do weather models work?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/19/how-do-weather-models-work)
- [What do quasi-geostrophic and ageostrophic mean?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/300/)
- [How can the following equations for meandering rivers be theoretically obtained?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/342/how-can-the-following-equations-for-meandering-rivers-be-theoretically-obtained)
- [How can I improve the numerical stability of a coastal hydrodynamic model?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/320/how-can-i-improve-the-numerical-stability-of-a-coastal-hydrodynamic-model)
- [Why do tropical cyclones not tear themselves apart?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/251/why-do-tropical-cyclones-not-tear-themselves-apart/419?noredirect=1#419)
- [Why is earth not a sphere?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/108/why-is-earth-not-a-sphere/110#110)
- [What causes waves to form the characteristic "breaking" shape as they approach the shoreline?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/421)
- [Why don't cold fronts and other steep-gradient weather effects just dissipate?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/69/why-dont-cold-fronts-and-other-steep-gradient-weather-effects-just-dissipate/451#451)

This is community wiki, so if you see something that would be good for this list, add it!

Comment: I think that 4 example posts is enough to show that MathJaX would be useful.

Comment: Another similar post on a different site had 10 posts, and they got it. Let's shoot for that.

Answer (score 1):

Can I use LaTeX/MathJax to edit formulas in my answers?

This feature is available on other SE sites, but it is not clear to me whether I will be able to use this here.

The capability to write mathematical formulas is essential for any meaningful communication about science beyond elementary school. Not supporting this would really limit this site to a non-expert site. That would be fine if that is how you intend the site to be defined.  Not supporting this would mean many Q&A would have to be posted on another site.

If this the meta-question people come to when looking for LaTex/MathJax or formatting help, then it would be very helpful to include the following links.

[There should be universal LaTeX/MathJax guide for sites supporting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it)

[MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/demos/)

[An Introduction to Using tex in the 
 Harvard Mathematics Department](http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/)

[Wikipedia Help:Displaying a formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula)

[Markdown help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: This thread is our request to SE to enable MathJax on this stack.

Comment: It will be Mark. hopefully.